# APIFunction on Images

Tags: image-processing, wolfram-cloud, api

Would someone example why my hello-world example is not working:

```
t = Thumbnail@ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}];
With[{cloudobject = 
   FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "FactorIntegerAPI"}]}, 
 CloudDeploy[
   APIFunction[{"x" -> "Image"}, ImageEffect[#x, "Charcoal"] &], 
   cloudobject, Permissions -> "Public"]
  URLFetch[URLBuild[cloudobject, {"x" -> t}]]]
```

It gives the following URI too long error:

[image]

Does anyone know the rate/size limitations on images for API functions and how to properly encode them?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you call the API with the image encoded as a URL parameter there will be image size limitations. The solution is to instead post multipart/form-data to the API:

```
With[{cloudobject = FileNameJoin[{$CloudRootDirectory, "ImageEffectAPI"}]}, 
   CloudDeploy[
      APIFunction[{"x" -> "Image"},
         ImageEffect[#x, "Charcoal"] & ], 
      cloudobject, Permissions -> "Public" ];
   ToExpression[
      URLFetch[cloudobject,
         "Method" -> "POST", 
         "MultipartElements" ->
            {{"x", "image/jpeg"} ->
               ExportString[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Lena"}], "JPEG"] } ] ] ]
```

[image: Lena ImageEffect Request MultipartFormData API]

The above solution deploys exactly the same API that the question proposes and returns a byte RawArray image string. The final image is generated by applying ToExpression to the RawArray string. It is perhaps preferable to deploy a slightly modified API, which returns a Base64 encoded image instead of a RawArray string:

```
APIFunction[{"x" -> "Image"}, 
   ExportString[
      ImageEffect[#x, "Charcoal"], {"Base64", "JPEG"}] & ]
```

Deploy and call this API exactly as above, but instead of ToExpression apply ImportString to the result:

```
ImportString[URLFetch[cloudobject, ... ], {"Base64", "JPEG"}]
```

**Comment:**

The documentation that an APIFunction can accept multipart/form-data is to say the least a bit tenuous: The APIFunction documentation mentions in the last Details and Options bullet that this function “allows the same options as FormFunction” and under Properties & Relations that the “APIFunction is designed to be interchangeable with FormFunction.” A FormFunction example in the Scope section gives an image file picker. From this one might guess that a FormFunction can accept multipart/form-data and that an APIFunction also can. After intercepting some FormFunction HTTP traffic and a bit of experimentation with URLFetch, the solution presented in this answer should in retrospect seem obvious.

Comment: Can you add how one would curl this api? @ChristopherHaydock