# Calling APIFunction from Javascript

Tags: wolfram-cloud, apifunction

I want to load [a csv file describing a graph](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6czwwdr21effr13/matrix9x9.csv?dl=0) from jQuery and call an APIFunction to evaluate its global clustering coefficient.

I'm not sure on how to call the APIFunction from the html form. I'm getting the following error. The matrix is not evaluated.

[image]

Here's my APIFunction code:

```
   CloudDeploy[
 APIFunction[{"myfile" -> "CSV"}, 
  N@GlobalClusteringCoefficient[
     AdjacencyGraph[Abs[Sign[#myfile]]]] &], Permissions -> "Public"]
```

My HTML:

```
 <html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(":file").css("background-color", "gray");
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form action="https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/9f99606b-f688-4737-8e2d-eecc03a810b7" method="get">
  File: <input type="file" name="myfile">
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Similar to: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/107727/apifunction-on-images

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work: First use a named [`CloudObject`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudObject.html) (that way you don't have to constantly update your web page every time you make changes to your [`APIFunction`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/APIFunction.html) and redeploy it):

```
CloudDeploy[ 
  APIFunction[{"myfile"->"CSV"}, Dimensions[#myfile]& ], 
  CloudObject["filetest"], 
  Permissions -> "Public" 
]
```

Note, I simplified the `APIFunction` code to just compute the [`Dimensions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dimensions.html) of the CSV file.

Next you need to change your web page as shown below (replace the `CloudObject` with the one generated by the above code. Note the addition of the `method="post"` and `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in the `<form>` tag (this is key to making this work):

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
  <script>
   $(document).ready(function(){$(":file").css("background-color", "gray");});
  </script>
 </head>
 <body>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="https://www.wolframcloud.com/objects/user-7053ce31-817f-4643-aec1-eda27051bba6/filetest">
   File: <input type="file" name="myfile">
   <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is what the web page looks like:

[image]

When I run this on your CSV file, I get back its dimensions (9x9):

[image]

Let me know if this helps!

(thanks to [Joel](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/594/joel-klein) who actually figured this out!)

Comment: Thanks! This works great. Do you know why we have to add enctype="multipart/form-data"?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4526273/what-does-enctype-multipart-form-data-mean