# How to make APIFunction accept parameters from body?

Tags: wolfram-cloud, apifunction

How to make `APIFunction` get its parameters from the body?

By default it uses the request URI, which is first insecure, and second, won't allow me to pass e.g. images to the function.

Comment: Is something like `APIFunction[{}, HTTPRequestData["Body"] &]` acceptable?

Comment: It also depends on how you are planning on making the request.  What headers are you using?

Comment: @chuy, thanks, this is exactly what I need. I expected it to be somewhere in the association. Write an answer and I will accept it

Comment: Perhaps your question is answered by [APIFunction on Images](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/107727/).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ultimately the body can be extracted by using [`HTTPRequestData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HTTPRequestData.html)

```
HTTPRequestData[]
```

will return an `Association` containing properties and values. Usually you can specify the specific property you want, like `"Body"` (I seem to remember some issues getting `"MultipartElements"` at some point in time).

```
obj = CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{}, HTTPRequestData["Body"] &]]

URLExecute[obj, {}, 
  "Body" -> "\"test body\"",
  "Headers" -> {"content-type" -> "text/plain" (*or whatever is appropriate*)}, 
  Method -> "POST"]
```

> ```
> "test body"
> ```

If your API is actually attached to a form, and your header when making the request is something like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data
```

you can use the following

```
CloudDeploy[APIFunction[{"i"-> "Image"}, #i &,"PNG"]]
```

This will echo back the image "i" (as labeled in your form). I put "PNG" for display purposes, you should change it to fit your needs.

Comment: With your addition of POST I'm getting `Missing["NotAvailable"]`.

Comment: @Kuba: ugh you are right, but without it that means its making a GET request.  I am going to look for a workaround.  The URLExecute/URLFetch functions are a mess.

Comment: Yep, I wasn't investigating closer but GET was my concern too. I find them a little bit chaotic too but I blame my limited experience in the area. Looking forward for news from your side then :)

Comment: @Kuba: it looks like the header needs to be specified.  I suppose that isn't too unreasonable,  but I would think it would fall back to "text/plain" by default.